# How to overwrite some bytes of a binary file with dd?

Tags: unix, binary, dd

I have a binary file and i want to replace the value `A2` at address `DEADBEEF` with some other value, say `A1`.

How can I do this with `dd`? If there are other tools that can do this, please suggest. But I plan to do this on iPhone so I can only work with most basic Unix tools.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```bash
printf '\xa1' | dd of=somefile bs=1 seek=$((0xdeadbeef)) conv=notrunc
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my machine. `somefile` end up truncated after the modified byte.

Comment: However, it works when `conv=notrunc` is at the end of the command.
`printf '\xa1' | dd of=somefile bs=1 seek=$((0xdeadbeef)) conv=notrunc`

Answer (score 0):

(Same answer, but doesn't fit into a comment:)

I wanted to preview the file content before applying the patch I wanted; `dd` uses different sets of arguments for input and output files, so remember to use `if` and `iseek`:

```
% dd if=somefile bs=1 iseek=4488884 count=12 conv=notrunc | hexdump -C
12+0 records in
12+0 records out
12 bytes copied, 0.000131 s, 91.6 kB/s
00000000  1f 04 00 71 40 02 00 54  a1 02 40 f9              |...q@..T..@.|
0000000c
```

And a multi-byte patch (`dd` will just overwrite with whatever stdin gives it, so no need to specify length):

```
% printf '\x40\x02\x00\x54' | dd of=somefile bs=1 seek=4488888 conv=notrunc
4+0 records in
4+0 records out
4 bytes copied, 0.000251 s, 15.9 kB/s
```