# change a few bytes in a large file without loading everything in memory using bash on linux

Tags: bash

in bash on linux is there a way to change a few bytes/characters in a large file? for example, seek to position x and then optionally delete a few characters, and then insert a few characters. I prefer to do this in bash.

Comment: Not doable in my opinion. Unless Bash has some kind of `mmap` implementation that you could use from within your script...

Comment: There's no easy way to do this unless you are doing an in-place, same-number-of-bytes replacement, in which case you can use `dd` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290816/how-to-overwrite-some-bytes-of-a-binary-file-with-dd).  If you need to alter the size of the file at all, you'll likely have to roll your own solution.  You can still use `dd`, and that's pretty fast, but you'd have to chunk off the before/after parts in separate `dd` commands and write a temporary file in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to make an "edit" to a file that changes the position of characters after the edit point ... except by reading and rewriting all characters after the edit point.

The reason for this is fundamental to the way that files are represented, and the way that file system APIs work.  And these in turn derive from the way that the physical storage devices work.

So a general solution would need to be implemented something like this (pseudo-code):

```
# Replace N bytes starting at position P with bytes B1, B2,...

open file in "random access, no truncation" mode 
seek to N + P
read remainder of file into a buffer.
seek to N
write bytes B1, B2, ...
write bytes from the buffer
close
```

(You could avoiding the entire "remainder of the file" into a buffer, but the logic is more complicated.  And tangential to what I'm trying to explain ...)

Anyway, I'm not aware of an existing utility that will do the above, but you could write an ad-hoc program to do that if you wanted to.

---

If the number of bytes you were replacing was exactly the same as the number of replacement bytes, you *could* do this with an in-place update.  According to [How to overwrite some bytes of a binary file with dd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290816/how-to-overwrite-some-bytes-of-a-binary-file-with-dd) you can do this with the "dd" command.  (The Answer demonstrates a 1 byte in-place update.)